# Why Can't I Inherit IO.Directory?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, system.io.directory

Why can't I create a `class` in `VB.NET` that `inherits` `System.IO.Directory`?  According to Lutz Roeder, it is *not* declared as `NotInheritable`!

I want to create a `utility class` that adds functionality to the `Directory class`.  For instance, I want to add a `Directory.Move` function.

Please advise and I will send you a six pack.  OK nevermind I'm not sending you anything but if you come to the bar tonight I will hook you up and then beat you in pool.

Comment: Thank you Jeff Atwood for editing my post and adding VB.NET tag.  No wonder you can't blog anymore!

Comment: Lol, he changed content.  I added the tag :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Meta Data of .NET

```
namespace System.IO
{
    // Summary:
    //     Exposes static methods for creating, moving, and enumerating through directories
    //     and subdirectories. This class cannot be inherited.
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public static class Directory
```

You cannot inherit from a Static Class.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using <s>C# 3.0</s> VB.NET 2008 -- then you could add an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)

Comment: I know, but what kind of programmer doesn't argue semantics? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the DirectoryInfo class, you will have access to a MoveTo function.

EDIT:  I'll correct myself... The static Directory class already has a Move method.

Comment: I don't care.  I am trying to rename a directory, not move it.

Comment: Won't moving the directory to the new name effectively rename it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that Reflector isn't picking up the sealed attribute correctly for VB (or perhaps just not displaying it properly). If you look at the IL, it is sealed:

class public abstract auto ansi **sealed** beforefieldinit Directory