# FxCop giving a warning on private constructor CA1823 and CA1053

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, optimization, fxcop

I have a class that looks like the following:

```
Public Class Utilities
    Public Shared Function blah(userCode As String) As String
        'doing some stuff
    End Function
End Class
```

I'm running FxCop 10 on it and it says:

```
"Because type 'Utilities' contains only 'static' (
'Shared' in Visual Basic) members, add a default private 
constructor to prevent the compiler from adding a default 
public constructor."
```

Ok, you're right Mr. FxCop, I'll add a private constructor:

```
Private Utilities()
```

Now I'm having:

```
"It appears that field 'Utilities.Utilities' is 
never used or is only ever assigned to. Use this field 
or remove it."
```

Any ideas of what should I do to get rid of both warnings?

Comment: The line you added is not a private constructor.  Constructors in VB are named New

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# this problem would be handled by marking the class as static, e.g.

```
public static class Utilities
{
   ...
}
```

A static class can only contain static (in VB shared) members.

I believe the equivalent in VB.NET is to use a module.

See [Marking A Class Static in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135841/marking-a-class-static-in-vb-net).