# add new string object method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, overloading

I have this codeline:

```
newUrl = Request.RawUrl.ToString.Replace(Server.UrlEncode(category), "")
```

When category="" I get the error: 
String cannot be of zero length.
Parameter name: oldValue

So I want to add a new replace method, that does except an empty string as parameter to replace.
I don't want to check if category is an empty string, since the check needs to happen a lot and will make my code too complex.
So I want to add a method "ReplaceNew" or overload the "Replace" method of the String object with an extra parameter "ignoreEmptyValue".

I tried:

```
Public Module CustomMethods

Public Function ReplaceEx(original As String, pattern As String, replacement As String) As String
    If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(pattern) Then
        Return original
    Else
        Return original.Replace(pattern, replacement)
    End If
End Function
End Module
```

And

```
Public Class GlobalFunctions

Public Shared Function ReplaceEx(original As String, pattern As String, replacement As String) As String
    If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(pattern) Then
        Return original
    Else
        Return original.Replace(pattern, replacement)
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

I then tried:

```
newUrl = Request.RawUrl.ToString.ReplaceEx(Server.UrlEncode(category), "")
```

But the ReplaceEx method is not available this way, I get the error:

'ReplaceEx' is not a member of 'String'.

I really want to have the ReplaceEx method available on the String object, since I don't want to restructure my code, but rather replace all .ToString.Replace methods with .ToString.ReplaceEx methods.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
public static string ReplaceEx(this string original, string pattern, string replacement)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
        return original;
    else
        return original.Replace(pattern, replacement);
}
```

and use the `ReplaceEx` in place of `Replace` as

```
newUrl = Request.RawUrl.ToString.ReplaceEx(Server.UrlEncode(category), "")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing multiple replace statement, so instead of restructuring my code, I'd rather replace all .tostring.replace methods with .tostring.replaceex methods. With your code that's not possible right? How can I make that happen?

Comment: @Floran Place that code inside a global static class, then use the ReplaceEx, in the place or Replace on your code. Make a test and you see.

Comment: I placed it inside a public class. How do I declare a global static class in vb.net? I did a Google search (found this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135841/marking-a-class-static-in-vb-net), changed it to: Public Module CustomMethods

    Public Function ReplaceEx(original As String, pattern As String, replacement As String) As String
        If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(pattern) Then
            Return original
        Else
            Return original.Replace(pattern, replacement)
        End If
    End Function
End Module but that didn't help.

Comment: @Floran well, I believe that you can place it in any class (not only static). Make a test

Comment: @Floran Yes I see that, you make an auto convert (?) from c# to vb. Now this code if you include it on your code, somewhere global, it will make available the ReplaceEx.

Comment: I did use an auto converter. I added the code to my Public GlobalFunctions class. However it does not extend the String object. I also fail to see where in your code it's defined that the ReplaceEx method should extend the String object? It only becomes available as a normal method, so via Globalfunctions.ReplaceEx...but that's not what I need.

Comment: @Floran before write it here I tested it and it work to me, but I can not help you on VB.

Answer (score 0):

This is to get it to work:

```
Module MyExtensions
<Extension()>
Public Function ReplaceEx(ByVal original As String, ByVal pattern As String, ByVal replacement As String) As String
    If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(pattern) Then
        Return original
    Else
        Return original.Replace(pattern, replacement)
    End If
End Function
End Module
```

Make sure that this line is in the code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
```