# Prevent implicit import of modules

Tags: vb.net

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135841/marking-a-class-static-in-vb-net), the equivalent of a C# static class in VB is  a module.

However, as stated [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289509(v=vs.71).aspx), "A module is implicitly imported into every source file in a project so the methods and properties of the module can be accessed without being fully qualified."

Is there a way to prevent this implicit import? Example:

```
Module moduleName
  Public Const field As String = "field"
End Module
```

In my classes, I want to be forced to use:

```
moduleName.field
```

Instead of just:

```
field
```

So when I read the code, I know where the "field" comes from (in C#, static classes are not implicitly imported).

Comment: If you don't want that behaviour, why don't you use a class?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to use a "NotInheritable Shared Class", however it's not valid in VB. The other post suggests to use a Module instead, which is indeed quite similar to a static class. The only problem is this implicit import. If there are no solutions, then I will go back to a class yes, because fully qualifying the field is quite important to me.

Comment: You could implement a `NotInheritable Class` and make all members shared.

Comment: @sloth: thanks, this answers my question indeed, I'll mark mine as a duplicate.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: as it is not possible to prevent the "implicit import", I'll do as you suggest, and use a "NotInheritable Class", even though it is not 100% the same as in C#. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthieu Funny enough, C# 6 added the possibility to invoke a static method without explicitly referencing the type...

Comment: @sloth You're right!!! I didn't know that. I just saw an example, how horrible the code looks like in my opinion:-)

Comment: @Matthieu Well, as with every feature, you can do good or you can do bad :-)